# Android Studio isn't showing Build Variants

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, build-variant

I'm recently struggling with a problem where my Build Variants is not working properly. I can't select variants, there is just a `-----` on the selection row.

[image]

I have tried to:

- delete my .idea folder, invalidate caches and everything
- Sync Project with Gradle Files

My buildConfig Gradle looks like:

```
  buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        resValue "string", "ADMOB_APP_ID", "\"${keystoreProperties["debugAdmobApiKey"]}\""
        resValue "string", "INSTERSTIAL_AD_ID", "\"${keystoreProperties["debugInterstialAdKey"]}\""
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        resValue "string", "ADMOB_APP_ID", "\"${keystoreProperties["releaseAdmobApiKey"]}\""
        resValue "string", "INSTERSTIAL_AD_ID", "\"${keystoreProperties["releaseInterstialAdKey"]}\""
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try to sync your project with the Gradle files via

File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files